# Lighttpd wrong config file syntax

Tags: lighttpd, configuration

Been trying for hours but just can't seem to get the correct syntax in my lighttpd configuration. As a last resort I am now asking the hive mind of server fault :P

I am trying to get trac hosted on the lighttpd server and keep php working at the same time. I include the config file "fastcgi.conf" which contains the following:

```
server.modules += ("mod_fastcgi")
index.file.names += ("index.php")

fastcgi.server = (
        ".php" = > ("localhost" = > (
                "bin-path" = > "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
                "socket" = > "/tmp/php-fastcgi.sock",
                "max-procs" = > 4, # default value
                "bin-environment" = > (
                        "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" = > "1", # default value
                        ),
                "broken-scriptfilename" = > "enable"
                )),
        "/trac" = >
        ("trac" = >
                ("socket" = > "/tmp/trac-fastcgi.sock",
                        "bin-path" = > fcgi_binary,
                        "check-local" = > "disable",
                        "bin-environment" = >
                        ("TRAC_ENV" = > "/mnt/external2/league-trac")
                        )
                )
        )
```

But i get the following error. I tried all examples and even directly copied some but still get errors. This is the error i get with above config file:

> 2014-03-09 12:48:44: (configfile.c.589) source: ../conf.d/fastcgi.conf
>   line: 9 pos: 16 use => for assignments in arrays  2014-03-09 12:48:44:
>   (configfile.c.954) configfile parser failed at: .php  2014-03-09
>   12:48:44: (configfile.c.957) source: ../lighttpd.conf line: 14 pos: 8
>   parser failed somehow near here: (EOL)

Can you guys help me out? I have no real experience with these kind of configs and just can't get it to work. Its probably something real simple and stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= >` is wrong, use `=>` (no space between the two characters)

Comment: Thanks. Another fault was index.file.names which should be index-file.names. And  fcgi_binary should have been replaced with the location of the fcgi binary in double quotes. But your answer made it possible to find the other 2 faults.